# Does a random phenomenon have a pre defined probability distribution? what does it mean for something to be random?

Tags: nondeterminism, randomness, cryptography

While studying Shannon's notion of perfect secrecy I came upon the idea that a bit is perfectly random if it happens to be 0 or 1 with an equal probability. What does this mean? Also, what can we say about the determinism here?

Answer (score 1):

Determinism is not broken, it is just that you are unaware of the value of the bit and can make no bet on it (because the two outcomes are as likely).

If you have some extra information such as "there are twice as many ones as zeroes in total" (but you still don't know where), you'd better bet one than zero to maximize your chances.